# Message attribute names starting with 'AWS.' or 'Amazon.' are reserved for use by Amazon

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, sms

I'm using nodejs. According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html) of AWS I should use the following sentence in order to change the senderid :
 MessageAttributes: {

```
'AWS.SNS.SMS.SENDERID': {
  'DataType': 'String',
  'StringValue': 'BLABLA'
}
```

When I'm running it, I get back this error:

```
ParameterValueInvalid: Message attribute names starting with 'AWS.' or 'Amazon.' are reserved for use by Amazon.
```

I believe that they have probably limited the access to use AWS after making the documentation, but I could not find another way to change the sellerid online.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct attribute name is `AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID` but you're using `AWS.SNS.SMS.SENDERID`.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe that was it.. tried to solve it for so much time :)